# Div should fill height

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

My page looks like this

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

The header has a fixed height. 
The main div has a background-image.

I want the main div to be displayed to fill the whole screen, so that the image is displayed at the very bottom.

So I did:

```
div#main {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-image: url(url);

    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

This didn't work, how can I set a divs height to fill the whole screen?

Another solution would be to set the image to the body:

```
body {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-image: url(url);
}
```

Here I got the problem, that on scroll the image is not fixed at the bottom. It actually fixed to the height of the windows size.

`background-attachment: fixed;` isn't the solution either, because the background-image doesn't scroll at all.

---

### Clarification

When the content is too large => There is a scroll bar, the background-image isn't fixed at the bottom anymore. That's the main problem. It's just the background-color of the body

---

@AndreaLigios

This is what I mean:

### [image]

## SOURCE

Check it out at http://themelandia.ilijatovilo.ch
Resize the window until the content is larger, and then scroll down.
Hopefully you'll see what I mean then.

Comment: With 1600 rep you should've prepared a Fiddle :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios I'm from **Objective-C** ;)

Comment: `div#wrapper {
    background: url(url) repeat-x left bottom;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%; width: 100%;
}`

Comment: Where is "some more content" coming from ?

Comment: I added it so it's easier to see, with "content" its the same behaviour ;)

Comment: Oh and it's, of course, in the `div#main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: final solution based on your site:

add

```
overflow: auto;
position: fixed;
```

to your div#wrapper rule.

---

EDIT:

New solution: http://jsfiddle.net/SxPyW/2/

added `top: 0;` , `padding-top: 100px;` and `z-index: 1;`

---

Do you mean this ?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SxPyW/

With absolute positioning, but with image scrolling up when scrolling the page (not the `fixed` behavior) ?

```
#main {  
   /* ... your stuff... */
    border: 2px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

(borders inserted to show boundaries, they overlap each other here, if you need borders adjust the `top` attribute accordingly)

Comment: Almost, can you resize the window until it reaches the middle of the "main" text? You'll see that the background-image isn't fixed at the bottom anymore

Comment: added a screenshot, what is it with z-index that I'd have to do

Comment: same behaviour, even in the fiddle, when resizing the background get's pushed upwards

Comment: Now that I can look at your site... it act the same even without the horizontal scrollbars, but just with the vertical scrollbars. Because if not `fixed`, an element is drawed in the viewport, the visible area, and when scrolling it stays there. You definitely need the `fixed` behavior... After that, you said the main div has a bacgkround image, while in your site it is the wrapper div to have it... :|

Comment: I got 100 tips and have to try them out all at once ^^ Sorry I'm changing things all the time

Comment: I really appreciate it man, however, it still doesn't work :D
Take a look at the print screen in the question. It shows what I mean. If you resize the window until the content is larger then the window, the get a vertical scroll bar. Now, when you scroll down, the background-image is fixed at the top, rather than the bottom

Comment: No man, it is not. Please, do not make me put a video on youtube of me scrolling your website :D My last edit is the one at the top of the message, tested directly on your site with Firebug editing and Firefox browser. Maybe it doesn't work on another browser ?

Comment: No, inject it directly in your site, leave the fiddle away :D (because your site is different from the fiddle, so i pointed directly to the real example)

Comment: Now you need to remove `position:absolute` from `div#main` (that before was not there :)

Comment: Done, now the background doesn't scroll anymore

Answer (score 1):

**Updated (r5)**

I use another `div` to contains the background, set its `position` to `fixed` and `z-index` to -1;

```
#bg-trick {
    background: url(http://images1.fanpop.com/images/image_uploads/Naruto-Uzumaki-uzumaki-naruto-964976_692_659.jpg) bottom center no-repeat;
    position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

The demo is updated here http://jsbin.com/idubom/5/edit

Comment: In order to get an element to a height of fullscreen every parent element above it should be 100% height as well. Basically you need to set height 100% on html, body and wrapper besides your current element.

Comment: Updated, add the `height:100%;` to `html` style as well.

Comment: Added more infos, hope it clarifies things

Comment: Yep, I have update the code, replace `height` by `min-height`. You could try now :)

Comment: But the image should be at the bottom :D

Comment: I have use another approach, maybe like a trick. Use another fixed `div` to store the background. See my updated demo.

Answer (score 1):

using the body technique but on the div styling... add the following to your style...

```
#main {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-image: url(url); 
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: In the question i wrote that I don't want that behaviour. I want the background to scroll with the content, but that it's always fixed at the bottom of the page

Comment: Sorry the forum screwed up my post it should be... #main {
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: left bottom;
background-image: url(url); 
background-attachment: fixed;
}

Comment: it's ok, you have to enable syntax highlighting, I did an edit, should be visible soon

Comment: Added more infos, hope it clarifies things

Comment: From looking at your sample it looks to me like your background image of the abstract hills and trees (green and blue) is attached to the CONTENT-WRAPPER DIV, And the background colour your getting is from your MAIN DIV. Is this right? If you answer YES then attach your style to the MAIN DIV instead of the CONTENT-WRAPPER-DIV   Also... recheck your LINK definitions in your HEAD section for some minor typos maybe that could be causing unwanted results too..

Answer (score 1):

You first need to set the height of the parent element to 100% to make the child element be able to stretch up to 100%

Set the width and height of html, body and #wrapper to 100% like this:

```
html, body, #wrapper
{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

Now apply background image in #wrapper(#wrapper is recommended rather than #main but if some part of the image being cut from the top bothers you then use #main)

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/28twc/) is a sample in jsfiddle.

Comment: Added more infos, hope it clarifies things

Answer (score 1):

Please check the updated [**[DEMO][1](http://jsfiddle.net/vjzuk/2/)**](http://jsfiddle.net/vjzuk/2/). This is what you are looking for.

**DESCRIPTION**:

```
    div#wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-image: url(http://s1.ibtimes.com/sites/www.ibtimes.com/files/styles/article_large/public/2012/08/20/298141-apple-aapl-stock-price-becomes-most-valuable-in-history-but-there-s-st.jpg);
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
div#header {
    height:80px;
    background-color:green;
}

div#main {
    padding: 60px 0px;
    min-height: 200px;
    bottom: 0;
}
div#contentWrap,div#headerWrap {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

** The key point is to add **position absolute/Fixed** on wrapper.

To display a image in full width you need to say body as a 100% of height. Rest seems fine to me in your code.

Here is also updated [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vjzuk/2/) May Be this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Like I wrote, `background-attachment: fixed;` is not the behaviour I need

Comment: @NSAddict Please check my Updated DEMO.

Answer (score -2):

you've already given height 100% to your div, additionaly add an innerHTML to your div because empty divs create such issues.

```
document.getElementById('my_empty_div').innerHTML = '&nbsp';
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: you can do the same in html as well:<div id='my_empty_div'> </div>. I've intentionally left a white space character. Also, it was nowhere mentioned that javascript is not required.

Comment: It's actually not empty -.-

Comment: this will be done in html only..m telling you that js is not needed for this purpose. css should be fine enough!